# Output data to the page from the database, node.js

Tags: node.js, express

Just started studying node.js, tell me how to collect all the necessary data from the database and pass it when loading the page? Or there is some other way, for example in the file .ejs is it possible to execute code to get data from the database, or is some other template engine used for such purposes?

In other words, how can i make several requests to the database at once and get the data before the page loads

File server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
_mysql_ = require('./db_connect'),
app = express(),
session = require('express-session');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('',express.static('public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/user', function(req, res){
  var DATA = {
    page: req.query.page,
    skills: {}
  };

  if(DATA.page== 'skills'){

    _mysql_.get("SELECT * FROM `sometable`",
    function(data){
       // mysql data
    });

    _mysql_.get("SELECT * FROM `sometable2`",
    function(data){
       // mysql data
    });

    _mysql_.get("SELECT * FROM `sometable3`",
    function(data){
       // mysql data
    });

   res.render('user',{data: DATA});

  }
});
```

File user.ejs

```
        <select onchange="return user.get_skills_list(this.value);">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
          <% data.skills.forEach(function(item){ %>
            <option value="<%= item.id %>"><%= item.name %></option>
          <% }); %>
        </select>
```

Comment: Hi, your question isn't clear but I guess you are searching for something Like data exchanger for requesting and sending data from client to server. Please have a look at tools like Ajax

Comment: I meant, how can i make several requests to the database at once and get the data before the page loads, ajax will get data after the page is loaded